# Is it possible to change parameter value in partial?

Tags: python, parameters, partial

I want to find a clear and efficient way to be able to change parameter value set for `functools.partial`.

Let's see a simple example:

```
from functools import partial

def fn(a,b,c,d,e):
   print(a,b,c,d,e)

fn12 = partial(fn, 1,2)
```

Later, I want to have something like:

```
fn12 [0] = 7
```

to replace the value on specific place without create a new partial, because it's pretty heavy code there.

Addition: i ask about general possibility to change partial value.

The naive example would be like :

```
def printme( a,b,c,d,e):
    print(a,b,c,d,e)

class my_partial:

    def __init__(self, fn, *args):

        self.__func__ = fn

        self. args = list(args) 

    def __call__(self, *next_args):

        call = self. args + list(next_args)       

        return self. __func__(* (call) )


fn12 = my_partial(printme,1,2)

fn12(3,4,5) 

fn12.args[1] = 7

fn12(3,4,5)
```

I need that for example for widgets, where action function is defined like :

```
  rb.config(command = partial(...))
```

but then I'd like to change some parameters given in partial. I could do a new partial again but that looks kinda messy.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea, what about everything else that's expecting it to have the original arguments?

Comment: So you want a partial application of `b`, but not `a`: `fn_b2 = partial(fn, b=2)`; then `fn12 = partial(fn_b2, a=1)`, and `fn72 = partial(fn_b2, a=7)`.

Comment: `fn12` should really be treated like a new function with a completely different signature, which doesn't even have an `a` (or `[0]`) parameter.

Comment: How is `fn12 = partial(fn, 7,2)` unclear (other than the bad name), inefficient or "pretty heavy code? But if you insist on having settable parameters, what's wrong with your `my_partial` class?

Comment: i sayd about partial implementation itself. actualy my_partial  microclass does everything you need

Answer (score 2):

If it is permissible to look into the implementation of `partial`, then using `__reduce__` and `__setstate__` you can replace the `args` wholesale:

```
from functools import partial

def fn(a,b,c,d,e):
   print(a,b,c,d,e)

fn12 = partial(fn, 1,2)

def replace_args(part, new_args):
    _,_, f = part.__reduce__()
    f, _, k, n = f
    part.__setstate__( (f, new_args, k, n) )

fn12('c','d','e')
replace_args(fn12, (7,2))
fn12('c','d','e')
```

Output:

```
1 2 c d e
7 2 c d e
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update partial parameters. For example if you have a function like this:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a*b
func = partial(f, b=2)
func(1) #  result: 1*2=2
```

Now, you can update partial parameter b like this:

```
func(1, b=7) # result: 1*7=7
```